# Select value from another table based on IF statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server DB I have two tables.

```
Customer | (CustomerAddressID1,CustomerAddressID2)
```

They link to Address table

```
Address | (AddressID,Postcode)
```

What is the best way to check the following condition in query?

If CustomerAddressID1 IS NOT NULL then get Postcode based on CustomerAddressID1 otherwise get Postcode based on CustomerAddressID2.

I was thinking along the lines of

Comment: That sounds like s simple use case for CASE WHEN, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Showing some sample input and expected results would be good.

Comment: More concerned about how join would work.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://dbfiddle.uk/Mv7L_l4T

Comment: @JonasMetzler that looks great will try. Appreciate it.